# How to add to cart in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create order:

**models.py**:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      image_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      image_size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      file_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      price = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
      start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
      ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.user)
```

**serializers.py**:

```
 class AddtocartSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
             model = OrderItem
             fields = ['image_number','title','image_size','file_type','price']

class CartSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = ['item',
                'start_date',
               'ordered_date'
              ]
```

**views.py**:

```
class AddtocartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      pagination_class = None
      queryset=OrderItem
      serializer_class = AddtocartSerializers

class CartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      pagination_class = None
      queryset=Order.objects.all()
      serializer_class = CartSerializers
```

**urls.py**: api endpint

```
 path('addtocart/',views.AddtocartView.as_view({'get':'list'}),name='addtocart'),
 path('cart/',views.CartView.as_view({'get':'list'}),name='cart'),
```

I am confused here; should I create new `order` objects from serialzers or views?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the created method on the AddtocartSerializers to add the order item to the order.

You can see more information about it here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

Comment: i'm still confused can you elaborate